# Подсчет количества совпадений в поиске

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется форма поиска:

```
<input type="text" id="task-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#users-table" placeholder="Фильтровать...">
```

Под этой формой выведен список имен

```
<tr><td><a href="#">Вася</a></td></tr> 
<tr><td><a href="#">Петя</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#">Маша</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#">Петя</a></td></tr>
```

При вводе скажем буквы "П" появляются имена на эту букву. Пытаюсь получить количество имен на эту букву следующим образом:

```
var search = $('#users-table').val().toLowerCase();
$('#users-table').on('keyup', function(){
if(search == ''){
var numItems = $('#users-table tbody tr').length;
}else{
var numItems = $(!(('#users-table tbody tr').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1)).length();
}
alert(numItems);
});
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var search = $('#task-table-filter').val().toLowerCase();
$('#task-table-filter').on('keyup', function(){
```

У вас у инпута есть айди, вы же берете значение непонятно откуда. Обращение к инпуту должно быть как я написал выше. Я так понимаю что `#users-table` это айди таблицы.
    У вас весь код неправильный. Не знаю какой там весь html но вот рабочий код.

```
var numItems = 0, countElements;
$('#task-table-filter').on('keyup', function(){
var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if(search == ''){
numItems = $('tr').length;
}else{
countElements = $('a');
$(countElements).each(function(){
   if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == search){
      numItems++;
   }
})
}
alert(numItems);
});
```

Нужно будет заменить в `countElements` на ваш селектор из таблицы. так как не знаю какая там у вас структура.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но теперь переменная numItems выводит количество позиций во всем списке. Нет ли ошибки вот в этой строке var numItems = $(!(('#users-table tbody tr').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1)).length();

Comment: есть ошибка) изменил свое сообщение

Comment: вместо цикла можно попробовать использовать [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Спасибо за комменты, они мне помогли